# Show standard warning icon in Qt4

Tags: qt, coding-style, icons

I'm trying to display a "warning" icon next to a `QLineEdit` if it contains invalid data. 
I was trying to use `QStyle::standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning)` to get a standard pixmap and place it inside a `QLabel`, and in some cases this seems to work. When running Gnome the icon is displayed correctly, but when running under KDE no icon is shown. I assume that the warning icon is simply not included in the style used under KDE.

What is the preferred way to display a "standard" warning icon in Qt? Does there exist some list which shows which icons are included in every style? How can I get an icon from a style that I know includes the warning icon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last time I had a similar problem, I found [this Qt labs discussion](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/10/27/update-on-standard-icons-in-qt/) useful. It informed me that [QIcon](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qicon.html) now (since 4.6 I believe) has a `QIcon::fromTheme` function that allows you to load an icon based on [the Freedesktop.org Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html), and in addition provide a fallback icon to be used if the current theme does not have the icon in question.

What I did was then to include some very basic icons for use as fallback, and in general specify icons only by their Freedesktop names. This gave a theme-consistent look almost always, and the program still worked in cases where people were missing icons.

As for the warning icon, I'm guessing/hoping that every theme must have the one named "dialog-warning", and that it's what you're looking for.

I hope this helps.

*Edit*: Oh and, in case you don't know, it can be useful to look at for example the [Tango icon set](http://tango.freedesktop.org/Tango_Icon_Library) to get a rough idea of what the Freedesktop names correspond to (although it is of course theme-dependent).

Answer (score 6):

Qt does [bundle a number of images](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Embedded_resources) that are resources that you can use in your own code. These images are a superset of those available via `standardIcon()` You may want to verify that the particular image is included in the versions of Qt you're targeting.

The end result could look like the following:

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/trolltech/styles/commonstyle/images/up-128.png");
// use pixmap as needed
```

Comment: Interesting. I can imagine this being very useful for supplying ``QIcon::fromTheme`` with a fallback.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who wants to know how to do this in a Windows environment you can:

Create a qLabel in your custom class, and then in the constructor of that class create a QIcon with the style you want, convert it into a pixmap and use the QLabel::setPixmap() function to apply it to the one you created:

```
QIcon icon = style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning); //or 
//whatever icon you choose
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(QSize(60, 60));
ui->iconLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);

ui->iconLabel->setScaledContents(true); //you can set this to fill the 
//dimensions of your qLabel if you wish.
```